# Watermark module not installing / fatal error - Prestashop 1.6

Tags: module, prestashop, watermark

We tried to install Watermark default module (from github) on Prestashop 1.6.1.23. After trying to install we have some fatal error:

[PrestaShop] Fatal error in module file... ...watermark.php
Call to undefined method Watermark::trans()

How can we resolve this problem?

Module is default, theme default also. PHP version is 7.

Best regards

Comment: Which one have you got? https://github.com/PrestaShop/watermark that one is for 1.7.6.0+

Comment: That's it... I found on github another version now. Thank you for your help!